# MySQL, search a database and tell what tables contain two specific columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with well over 90 tables and I am trying to figure which, if any, of them have the same two specific columns.  The code I am looking for would be something like this:

```
SHOW TABLES IN `database` 
      WHERE column = 'columnA' 
        AND column = 'columnB';`
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Time to learn about [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you all tables having either of the two columns, which you can browse through to find what you need.

```
  select *
    from information_schema.columns
   where column_name in ('columnA', 'columnB')
order by table_name, column_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS `schema`, TABLE_NAME AS `table`, COLUMN_NAME AS `column` 
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN('column1','column2')
```